# Retrieve Object classes

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class named User and every time user clicks on the register button in RegisterActivity.java , will use firebase authentication create userwithemailandpassword method and inside it generates a new user object using User class and stored that user object to firestore.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if(task.isSuccessful()){
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Sign Up successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //store user data
        userid=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DocumentReference documentReference=fstore.collection("user").document(userid);
        User user=new User(name,userid,"user",email,newvalue);
        documentReference.set(user);

        Intent intent=new Intent(SignUp.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"SignUp Failed"+task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Now, in another activity, I want to update the value of newvalue to that particular object. I can update to Firestore document but  don't know how to refer to that particular object since in the register activity is called user.

```
User user=new User(name,userid,"user",email,newvalue);
```

This is my User class:

```
public class User {
    String username;
    String role;
    String email;
    String userid;
    String newvalue;

    public User(){

    }
    public User(String username, String userid, String role, String email,String newvalue) {
        this.username = username;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.role = role;
        this.email = email;
        this.token=token;
        this.newvalue=newvalue;
    }
    public String getnewValue() {
            return newvalue;
    }

    public void setnewvalue(String newvalue) {
        this.newvalue = newvalue;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return username;}
}
```

Comment: First of all, show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact document you want to update.

Comment: Did you find the below posted answer useful or are you looking for something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [**`Create a password-based account`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), it looks like you are using `task.isSuccessful` as a method but actually it is boolean. You are setting new User document correctly and for your

> I want to update the value of newvalue to that particular object. I can update the Firestore document but don't know how to refer to that particular object since in the register activity is called user.

Query you can get the User uid anywhere in application with `auth.currentUser.uid` assuming user is already logged in then you can use [**`Custom objects`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) to get the user document as follows:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
val docRef = db.collection("user").document(userId)
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    val user = documentSnapshot.toObject<User>() // there’s your retrieved Object class
}
```

To update the `newValue` field you can update as follows:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
val docRef = db.collection("user").document(userId)
docRef
     .update("newvalue", newValue) // ⇐ you can also update the other fields 
     .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!") }
     .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e) }
```